# Tensorflow conv2d_transpose Invalid argument error

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

When I use tensorflow to train my model, I met a puzzled problem, I got an Error, such as like this:
`Invalid argument: Conv2DSlowBackpropInput: input and out_backprop must have the same batch size`
Much more confusing, the training can run some steps, my batch_size = 64, when the training reached 101 steps, the training stopped and throw this Error.

I want to use TensorFlow to train my model, I want to use conv2d_transpose firstly, in order to realize upsampling, then I want to use conv2d, after each conv2d_transpose, I add a batch_normalization after the conv2d_transpose.

But when I train my model, I met a puzzled problem, the model can run some steps, but when it reached a certain steps, it will throw a problem.

The problem is like this:
`Invalid argument: Conv2DSlowBackpropInput: input and out_backprop must have the same batch size, input batch: 64 outbackprop batch: 56 batch_dim: 0`

My batch_size is 64.

```py
h1 = deconv2d(
            input_=h0,
            output_shape=[
                batch_size,
                s_h8,
                s_w8,
                f_dim * 4
            ],
            name="deconv1")

h1 = tf.nn.relu(d_bn_1(h1))  

def deconv2d(input_, output_shape,
             k_h=5, k_w=5, d_h=2, d_w=2, stddev=0.02,
             name="deconv2d", with_w=False):
    with tf.variable_scope(name):

        # batch_size = tf.shape(input_)[0]
        #
        # stack_shape = tf.stack([batch_size, output_shape[1], output_shape[2], output_shape[3]])

        w = tf.get_variable('w', [k_h, k_w, output_shape[-1], input_.get_shape()[-1]],
                            initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(stddev=stddev))


        try:
            deconv = tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(input_, w, output_shape=output_shape,
                                            strides=[1, d_h, d_w, 1], padding="SAME")

        # Support for verisons of TensorFlow before 0.7.0
        except AttributeError:
            deconv = tf.nn.deconv2d(input_, w, output_shape=output_shape,
                                    strides=[1, d_h, d_w, 1])

        biases = tf.get_variable('biases', [output_shape[-1]], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
        deconv = tf.reshape(tf.nn.bias_add(deconv, biases), deconv.get_shape())
        print(name+" shape", deconv.get_shape())

        if with_w:
            return deconv, w, biases
        else:
            return deconv
```

I expect the model can train fluently, and I hope anyone else can help me solve this problem. I tried some methods, but it didn't work.
Thank you very much!!!!

Answer (score 0):

After many attempts, finally I find where the mistake is!!!
Well, we need to use tf.reshape() after the conv2d_transpose, but it's not enough, we also need to use tf.reshape() after the conv2d.
The reason why we need tf.reshape() after the conv2d_transpose and conv2d is maybe the shape of Tensor will be lost in the training.
Then, the problem is settled!!!